# Tkinter Entry Box Font not changing with default

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a GUI for an application I am building, and I want to give users the option to update the font style and size. Below is what I have done so far and this works for changing the font on buttons & labels, but it doesn't change the font of any of the Entry() widgets, which is probably the most important text I want the user to be able to change. I know I can initialize the Entry() widget font by providing something like this `font=('Arial Bold', 16)` which works, but it doesn't allow the user any control.

I did figure out that you can change specific widgets using `.config(font=('Arial Bold', 16))`. So theoretically, I could include this in my `apply_font()` function for every Entry() widget, but that can't be the only way, right? I imagine there has to be a way to globally edit the font all Entry() widgets use.

How can I accomplish this?

```
def call_font_window():
    font_window = tk.Toplevel()
    font_window.title('Fonts')
    font_window.resizable(False, False)
    font_window.geometry('350x150')
    font_window.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

    font_type_label = tk.Label(font_window, text='Font Type: ')
    font_size_label = tk.Label(font_window, text='Font Size: ')  

    font_type_options = [def_family, 'Calibri', 'Arial', 'Arial Bold', 'Times New Roman']
    font_size_options = [def_size, 10, 12, 14, 16]

    font_type_entry = tk.OptionMenu(font_window, font_type_var, *font_type_options)
    font_size_entry = tk.OptionMenu(font_window, font_size_var, *font_size_options)

    font_type_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NEW')
    font_size_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='NEW')
    font_type_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='NEW')
    font_size_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='NEW')

    def apply_font():
        def_font.configure(family=font_type_var.get(), size=font_size_var.get())


    apply_button = tk.Button(font_window, text='Apply', command=apply_font)
    apply_button.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='NEW')

    font_window.grab_set()
    font_window.mainloop()

.
.
.

def_font = font.nametofont("TkDefaultFont")
def_family = copy.deepcopy(def_font['family'])
def_size = copy.deepcopy(def_font['size'])
font_type_var = tk.StringVar(value=def_font['family'])
font_size_var = tk.IntVar(value=def_font['size'])

menubar = tk.Menu(root)
view_options = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0) 
view_options.add_command(label="Font", command=call_font_window)
view_options.add_separator() 
menubar.add_cascade(label="View", menu=view_options)
root.config(menu=menubar)
.
.
.
```

Comment: I don't see any `Entry` widgets in this code.

Comment: This isn't the entirety of the code. I tried to emphasize that with the "vertical ellipses" but looks like that fell short of communicating my message. I tried to only include the section of code that was relevant to the problem I was trying to solve

Comment: You don’t have to include all of your code, certainly. But your question mentioned `Entry` widgets specifically, so it’s a bit confusing to exclude them altogether.

Comment: In my defense, I got exactly the answer I was looking for where a global default setting is changed. So I did something right :)

Answer (score 2):

All the widgets fonts do not specifies by `TkDefaultFont` font. Go to [TkDocs Tutorial - Fonts](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/fonts.html) `Standard Fonts` section for more information.

You had better chage apply_font function as follow:

```
def apply_font():
    font_ = font.nametofont("TkDefaultFont")
    font_.configure(family=font_type_var.get(), size=font_size_var.get())
    font_ = font.nametofont("TkTextFont")
    font_.configure(family=font_type_var.get(), size=font_size_var.get())
```

Comment: This is much better than the solution I figured out. Thanks! I figured there had to be something like this. I'm bookmarking that link as it is exactly what I was trying to find but failed miserably at. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution, though I don't think it is the best way to go about this so please provide alternatives if they are available.

I imported gc (garbage collector) and added the following to my apply_font function:

```
for obj in gc.get_referrers(tk.Entry):
            if obj.__class__ is tk.Entry:
                obj.config(font=(font_type_var.get(), font_size_var.get()))
```

I'm calling this a win for now as it does the thing I'd like it to do.